# Unable to correctly interpret format specifiers in resource path

Tags: objective-c, xcode, url, string-formatting

I am trying to retrieve some information from the server via the following objective C resource path. However, I was unable to get my results as the resource path passed to the server is altered as shown below (server console)

```
//Objective C code
NSString *resourcePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/sm/search?limit=100&term=%@&types%5B%5D=users&types%5B%5D=questions&types%5B%5D=topics",searchString];


//Server console
[GET /sm/search?limit=100&term=Afhd&types5803200164=users&types51107296256=questions&types5368849=topics]
```

How can I update my code so that the server can recognize the regular expressions (%5B%5D) in my resource path instead of converting them?

Comment: These are not regexes at all, but string formats. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to post the following url "/sm/search?limit=100&term=%@&types%5B%5D=users&types%5B%5D=questions&types%5B%5D=topics" to server. I do not want the %5B%D to be converted to some other value when posting to server

Comment: And what if you try and just use a plain string instead of `stringWithFormat`?

Comment: Oh, I see... Can you try and double all `%`?

Comment: Can I do that? Cos there is a variable I need to pass into the string 'term=%@"

Comment: Well, I mean, all but for the variable you need to pass

Comment: Yeap it works. Can you add this as an answer so that I can accept it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use `stringWithFormat`, it means format specifiers start with `%`.

If you want to leave `%5d` etc intact in the output, you have to double the percent signs: `%%5d`.

So, you have to double all of them, except the one in `term=%@`, so that the value of `stringSearch` get into the result.